# substring in string shell script from last character

Tags: shell, sh, ksh

i have a text like this : 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@111.11.11.111:1521/DDEV'

How can i get from last characters to 1.th "/" of text using shell script?

So i need to use    "DDEV"

Regards

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO its highly encouraged for users to add their efforts in form of code in their question, so kindly do add the same in your question, thank you.

Comment: The duplicate is about filenames but getting the thing after the slash in a string is obviously applicable to any string with a slash.